# How do you name a property of an object with a string plus a variable?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, object, javascript-objects

If I have an object:

```
var enemies = {};
var enemyNumber = 0;
```

and then how do I make a new property of that object which is named after a string + a variable, like this (I know this is not valid javascript):

```
enemyNumber++;
enemies.enemy + enemyNumber.toString() = {};
```

(`enemies.enemy + enemyNumber.toString()` is another object)

Comment: You're looking for arrays.

Comment: Eh, your question is super confusing... Example?

Comment: This is missing an example providing context.

Comment: It will depend on your use case, but an array is almost certainly a better way of storing your enemies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how:

```
enemies['enemy' + enemyNumber] = {}
```

In JavaScript, the dot operator is interchangeable with bracket notation.  Which means `enemies.enemy1` is the same as `enemies['enemy1']`.  The bracket notation is more indirect, which allows you to use expressions to refer to the object's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Add dynamically properties to your `enemies`  object :

```
var enemies = {};
var enemyNumber = 0;
enemies.enemy="Coco";
...
enemies.enemyNumber = enemies.enemy + enemyNumber;
```

The `toString()` is not required when you concatenate a String and a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give each object a sequential identifier:

```
var enemies = { };
var enemyNumber = 0;

function addEnemy(attributes) {
  attributes.id = enemyNumber;
  enemies[enemyNumber] = attributes;
  enemyNumber++;
}

addEnemy({ name: 'Boss Man' });
```

Remember that you can reference properties of an object with the `[...]` notation and compute values that way. `x.y` and `x['y']` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use brackets to create a dynamic property:

```js
var enemies = {};
var enemyNumber = 0;

enemyNumber++;
enemies['enemy' + enemyNumber] = {};

console.log(enemies);
```